# How do I initialize a window in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsapplication

For a Mac graphics application (not iPhone), I need something like a main method in Java, the first method that gets a program going. I've been looking at things like NSViewController and NSWindow object. I've looked around but can't find an answer to this seemingly easy question anywhere. (I am very new at this by the way)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Cocoa project from one of the Xcode "Cocoa Application" templates, you'll get a main.m file that includes the usual startup code.

Try working through one of the tutorial projects that you'll find in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the project templates, the startup code is in the ApplicationDelegate file. The `main.m`, for a Cocoa application, sets up the run loop, runs NSApplication (as you can see in the Info.plist file under the 'Principle class' key.

This then loads the nib file that is specified in the Info.plist file (under the 'Main nib file base name' key). The default is MainMenu.xib. Now have a look at this nib file.

This is already set up by the template to have a 'Files's Owner' of NSApplication (the class that loaded the nib) But There is also a blue block which represents the application delegate. This is already filled out with one delegate method one outlet.

The delegate method is `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` This method is called by the application. This is only one of the possible delegate methods that it can handle, but it is sent after the run loop is started but before the application receives any events. It is the common place to put your initialisation code. It is in here that you should start to set up your window, which you can get to using the pre-supplied `window` outlet.

This is just a quick summary. A handy referenece is [on Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/cocoa-application-startup.html) and [Apple's Introduction to Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000005i) Architecture document.